# Paste values from array into string

Tags: php, arrays

If have this array:

```
$a = array("one", "two", "three");
```

I want to transform this into this string:

```
$s = "one, two, three";
```

### Is there a paste function in PHP?

E.g.:

```
$s = paste($a, sep=", ");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$s = implode(', ',$a);
```

Comment: shoulb be `$s = implode(', ',$a);` no? (`', '` instead of `','`)

Comment: ya sure. ',' is separator we can use any string or special character.

Comment: This again shows that you need to know the answer to be able to search for it :-( In other programming languages (e.g. `R`) this operation is called `paste`, so why doesn't the documentation for `implode` contain that common term? Would make finding this so much easier. Thank you for helping me, @Manibharathi!

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array("one", "two", "three");

foreach($a as $value) {
   $string = $string . ($value != '' ? '' : ', ') . $value;
}
```

Comment: Haha, ternary operator. I'm confused! ;)

Comment: You know I was trying to come up with the least obvious answer right? I mean 681 rep and your asking about array imploding? :)

Comment: My rep is for asking noob questions that other noobs find helpful, not for knowing stuff :-)

Comment: Ah ok, sorry for my strange answer then. It's correct though! ;)